# Get interactive shell with node js when invoking c program

Tags: node.js, c, child-process

I want to build an online interactive shell that runs c programming but as soon I put scanf in my code  it just ignores all the code until I give it all the inputs at first and then it gives me buffered code at once.

Here is my code:

```js
childProcess = cp.spawn("/output.out")

childProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  io.to(clientId).emit("result", data.toString() + "\n")
})

childProcess.on("data", (data) => {
  io.to(clientId).emit("result", data.toString())
})

childProcess.on("error", (err) => {
  io.to(clientId).emit("result", err.message.toString())
})
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float num1;
    double num2;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    printf("Enter another number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &num2);

    printf("num1 = %f\n", num1);
    printf("num2 = %lf", num2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output (it's waiting for me to give the input at first then it runs the code)

```
5
5
Enter a number: Enter another number: num1 = 5.000000
num2 = 5.000000
```

The expected output should be

```
Enter a number: 5
Enter another number: 5
num1 = 5.000000
num2 = 5.000000
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you aware of how `scanf` handles separators like spaces or newlines? Or how `printf` without a newline might need a flush?

Comment: I'm new to  C  actually can you provide a link for the flush so I can read more about it?

Comment: `man flush` or a search for `c man flush` will give you a good place to start. If you're writing C, keep a [solid reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) on hand at all times.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin).

Comment: I'm using windows, so I'm struggling to find a command in windows that unbuffer the stdout.

Comment: That other answer has a number of approaches worth trying.

Comment: That really helped me alot tysm !

Comment: yes, Now I know that printf() needs a flush after it